# How to show more that six custom ribbon commands in office.js Excel add-in

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

It is observed that we could not add more than six custom ribbon commands in single group and below are the observations.

**For Desktop Version**

1. When trying to add more than six custom ribbon commands in single group then it is only showing first six commands and rest of the commands are not shown.

**For Online Version**

1. When trying to add more than six custom ribbon commands in single group and trying to upload manifest file in online excel version it is showing alert message **"Your add-in manifest is not valid"**.

Hence kindly confirm that is there any option to implement more than six commands in single group or do we need to create another group for rest of the commands which are greater that six.

Comment: @rick... Have you had a chance looking into this?

Comment: Do you have a `<Group>` element in your manifest and there are more than 6 `<Control>` elements inside it?

Comment: Yes Rick..You are correct..Yes the same structure it is implemented otherwise manifest error happens. Also with that in desktop version even i can able to see only 6 commands if we have added more than 6 in manifest....But the same case for online version manifest could not getting uploaded...

Comment: @RickKirkham...any update please?

Comment: @RickKirkham.....   Based on below reference              https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/design/add-in-commands.md#Debugging.....mentioned "Place commands on a custom tab if you have more than six top-level commands."  but It could not achieve in Excel add-in...

Comment: That line from the documentation is talking about tabs, not groups within a tab. You can have more than 6 commands on a tab, but no more than 6 can be in the same group. See Lillian's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create another group for any controls over 6 - this limit is by design. A group can only have 6 controls maximum. There are, however, no limits on the number of groups you can have.